# Sending an image through the body of a PUT request

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, httpclient

Title says it all. I need to send an image through the body of a PUT request. This is the code I currently have.

```cs
    static class Request
    {
        private readonly static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public static async Task<UploadRequest> Upload(string uri, string path)
        {

            FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            MultipartContent content = new MultipartContent();
            content.Add(streamContent);

            Debug.WriteLine("Making a PUT request");
            var response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadRequest>(result);

            fileStream.Close();
            Debug.WriteLine("Request made, returning result");

            return deserializedResult;
        }
}
```

Instead of using `MultipartContent` I instead passed in `streamContent` directly into `client.PutAsync` like so.

```cs
FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

Debug.WriteLine("Making a PUT request");
var response = await client.PutAsync(uri, streamContent);
```

However they both produce the same error on my api. Which is `"message": "You did not upload an image."`. I've checked the actual content of what I've passed in, in both cases when I passed in `MultipartContent` or `streamContent` into `PutAsync`.

The respective output (in order of which I've mentioned them) is `System.Net.Http.MultipartContent` and `System.Net.Http.StreamContent` so what exactly am I passing into the body?

## Note

I previously asked the wrong question. This is the appropriate one.

Comment: So you are trying to add a full image (data) to a http header ? So how did you get the idea for this, what is requiring it, what makes you think you need to do this?

Comment: "So you are trying to add a full image (data) to a http header" I'm not too sure what this means. But everything else in order. I got the idea because someone told me to send an image over to the api, then get the api to resize it. I need to do this because of the same reasons as above.

Comment: You only get 16k bytes in an HTTP header. Since it'd have to be base64 encoded, you really only get about 11k bytes your image could be. That's not a lot of image data. And pretty unorthodox to boot.

Comment: My guess is you would likely want to post it in the body

Comment: @Andy if the way I'm thinking of doing it is unorthodox, what do you recommend?

Comment: what @00110001 said -- use HTTP Post/Put method and put it in the body of the request.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot more sense. I don't know why I thought It has to be sent through the headers. I think I was looking at the Postman app and thought I was in the headers tab without actually checking.

Comment: @00110001 I've been trying to send the image through the body of the PUT request, and nothing I've tried works. I also updated the question, since I asked the wrong one.